# No warning for implicit cast of bool to floating type?

Tags: c++, clang, compiler-warnings, implicit-conversion

Looks like this snippet compiles in clang without warning, even with -Weverything:

```
double x;
...
if (fabs(x > 1.0)) {
   ...
}
```

Am I missing something? Or do the compiler and C++ standard think that casting `bool` to `double` is something that makes sense?

Comment: The C and C++ standards don't require any warnings for this. But I would raise a bug with the clang people for this one. I expect it won't get fixed urgently, but it may get done eventually.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a consequence of making `bool` an integral type. According to C++ standard, section 3.9.1.6

> Values of type bool are either `true` or `false` (Note: There are no `signed`, `unsigned`, `short`, or `long` `bool` types or values. — end note) **Values of type bool participate in integral promotions**. (emphasis is added)

This makes values of `bool` expressions to be promoted to `float` in the same way the `int`s are promoted, without a warning, as described in section 4.5.6:

> A prvalue of type `bool` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int`, with `false` becoming zero and `true` becoming one.

**EDIT :** Starting with C++11 `fabs` offers additional overloads for integral types, so the promotion goes directly from `bool` to `int`, and stops there, because an overload of `fabs` is available for it.

Comment: this answer can possibly change, by a touch, if OP is using C++11 since in C++11 the `fabs` function not only offers signatures for `float`, `double` and `long double` arguments but also for integral types, so in that case the implicit cast or promotion is from `bool` to `int`, not `bool` -> `int` -> `float`.