# Prevent implicit conversion from bool to char

Tags: c++, char, boolean, implicit-conversion

I noticed that in C++ bool is implicitly converted to char. I realize that they're both stored as 1 byte, but they're fundamentally different types. Is there some compiler flag or something I can set to prevent an implicit conversion between the two? `char` being automatically converted to `bool` makes sense, but not the other way around.

for example, the following is valid:

```
char test = true;
```

I'm using Xcode with C++17

Comment: *"char being automatically converted to bool makes sense, but not the other way around."* Are you sure? Seems opposite to me. Every `bool` fits in a `char` but not the other way around.

Comment: What are you using to compile?

Comment: _"...If the source type is bool, the value false is converted to zero and the value true is converted to the value one of the destination type ..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_conversions

Comment: ... and a `char` can be implicitly converted to a `short` and a `short` can be implicitly converted to an `int` and ... so on.

Comment: @TedLyngmo it's the `bool` that is being converted

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes so there is no conversion of a `char` going on.  The `bool` is implicitly converted to an integer type and char is an integer type.

Comment: @TedLyngmo sorry miss-read your comment didn't realise you quoting the OP.

Comment: @RichardCritten My mistake, I didn't mean it to look like a comment to your comment :-)

Comment: `char test = strict<char>(true);` will fail to compile.  Just need to make the `strict` template class that disallows anything that not the type.

Comment: The best answer I believe is: live with it. It is a choice C++ made long ago. It's not great, but fighting against it is even worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This conversion is mandated by the C++ standard (part of the [integral conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_conversions)), so it is not possible to disable this conversion and remain a compliant C++ compiler.

It is possible for compilers to offer non-compliant extensions, but for something like this they would probably prefer a warning to going non-compliant. However, I was not able to find a compiler that offers such a warning (see, for example, [No warning for implicit cast of bool to floating type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874077/no-warning-for-implicit-cast-of-bool-to-floating-type)).

Still, an answer might exist in the form of non-compiler tools. It looks like [clang-tidy](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/index.html) includes [a check for implicit conversions from bool](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability-implicit-bool-conversion.html).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution based on the comment by @Eljay:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
T strict(U u)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, U>);
    return u;
}
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
char test  = strict<char>(true);  // error
char test  = strict<char>('a');   // ok
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/T483ne).

Comment: Nice!  That's even cleaner and simpler than what I cobbled together.

Answer (score -3):

char is int, so conversion is ok.

if you dont want this to happen you can do function with same name, but with bool as parameter. You can do the definition only, so if you do call it with bool it will compile but wont link.

Will show you example as soon as I am on PC